# when is a spring bean instantiated

Tags: java, spring

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
    "com/springinaction/springidol/spring-idol.xml");
Performer performer = (Performer) ctx.getBean("duke");
performer.perform();
```

In the above, when are the beans instantiated, when the ApplicationContext is created or when the getBean() is called?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Assuming the bean is a singleton, and isn't configured for lazy initialisation, then it's created when the context is started up.  `getBean()` just fishes it out.

Lazy-init beans will only be initialised when first referenced, but this is not the default. Scoped beans (e.g. prototype-scoped) will also only be created when first referenced.

Comment: If a BeanFactory is used, are the beans lazily loaded?

Comment: @java_geek: Well `BeanFactory` is just an interface, it depends which implementation you use, but generally yes, the same holds for most (if not all) `BeanFactory` implementations.

Comment: @ Skaffman : Sorry , I understand that if bean have scope is singleton it will created when new applicantionContext But how to test is it created or no? In prototype I call getBeanDefinitionNames it still appear

Answer (score 17):

According to Spring [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-lazy-init),

> The default behavior for ApplicationContext implementations is to eagerly pre-instantiate all singleton beans at startup.

Also, you can set them to load lazily.

Comment: thats the behavior for singleton beans. but what is the behavior for normal beans

Comment: @java_geek: Singletons *are* normal. they're the default. What's normal for you?

Comment: i wanted to know if singleton=false is set for the bean

Answer (score 15):

For reference, see

- [Lazy-initialized beans](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lazy-init) and
- [Bean scopes](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes)

Here's a brief description of when beans are created:

- A singleton bean (which is the default scope) that does not have the lazy-init property set to true (default is false) is constructed when the application context is created
- A singleton bean that does have the lazy-init property set to true is constructed when it is first requested
- A bean set in any other scope is created when it is first requested (for that scope).

Answer (score 3):

1. By default, all beans are singletons, so whenever Application context gets created, they are all pre-loaded. If, specifically, any singleton bean has an attribute lazy-init="true" set, it will be lazy-loaded, i.e. it will be instantiated when the getBean method is called for the first time.
2. For other scopes, beans will be instantiated whenever they are requested.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what is the scope of the bean you are calling with getBean() method.
If it is 'Singleton', it is pre-instantiated by the ApplicationContext.

If you are using BeanFactory as an IOC Container, then it uses lazy initialization and the beans will be instantiated only when you call the getBean() method.

This is an advantage of ApplicationContext over BeanFactory that it solves Circular Dependency problem.

Comment: Hi @Shubham I am a beginner to spring. I wanted to know that if a bean is prototype scoped then it gets instantiated only when getBean will be called right. I observe singleton gets created even though we don't use getBean?

Answer (score 1):

By default, Spring ApplicationContext eagerly creates and initializes all ‘singleton scoped‘ beans during application startup itself. ApplicationContext makes the bean available in BeanFactory. getBean() returns the instance of the bean.

Answer (score 0):

By default it's created when the context is started up but the order depends on dependencies.
If we have the following classes :

```
@Component
public  class A{

}

@Component
public class B{
    @Autowired
    A a;

}
```

Class A will be created before class B because class B depends on class A.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, when you run ApplicationContext, it automatically creates all the Annotated beans and makes ready them to use for you.

If you don't need some of them, you can annotate them with @Lazy and they will not instantiated when you run the application