# How to invoke @PostConstruct on request scoped bean before @HandleBeforeCreate handler?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-rest

In my Spring application I have a bean with *request* scope:

```
@Component
@Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class MyBean {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
       ...
    }
```

I have also a MongoDB event handler:

```
@Component
@RepositoryEventHandler
public class MyEventHandler {

    @HandleBeforeCreate
    public void beforeCreateInstance(Object instance) {
        ...
    }
 }
```

When I call Spring Data REST endpoint to save my resource, the `@HandleBeforeCreate` gets invoked first and `@PostConstruct` gets invoked afterwards.

How can I change the order of this invocations? I'd like to invoke `@PostConstruct` on `MyBean` before the MongoDB event handlers kick in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [explained in this answer, scoped beans get only initialized when the get referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4454244/66686). So if `MyEventHandler` references a `MyBean` the `MyBean` should get initialized, including any `PostConstruct` processing.

Of course, it would be weird to depend on a bean that you then don't use. That's exactly the purpose of [`@DependsOn`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/DependsOn.html). So change your `MyEventHandler` like this:

```
@Component
@RepositoryEventHandler
@DependsOn("myBean")
public class MyEventHandler {

    @HandleBeforeCreate
    public void beforeCreateInstance(Object instance) {
         ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to help :(
MyEventHandler and  MyBean are defined in different jars. They get pulled together during the build and instantiated using component scan via package names. I have logged out the sequence of handler methods invocations after adding `@DependsOn` and I don't think that it affects order of invocation (I can still see MyEventHandler being called before MyBean.init(). The DependsOn also seems to be active, since context doesn't start if bean name is wrong or absent.
Also tried to set `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)` on MyBean with no result as well.

Comment: Actually, I didn't notice, by MyEventHandler was dependent on MyBean via `@Autowired` even before, I'll update example in the question.

Comment: does the @PostConstruct handling happen before or after the call to `someMethod`?

Comment: I am confused now as well. I removed all additional annotations and brought example to the one described in the question now. It seams that `@PostConstruct` gets invoked before beforeCreateInstance() and someNethod() but then it gets invoked second time on another thread. Eclipse debugger glitches to stop on first invocation and it seems that I recognized second `@PostConstruct` invocation as being "after" beforeCreateInstance(). Still investigating..

Comment: I think that was the problem. Another EventHandler that didn't have @Autowired dependency to MyBean has added to my confusion. For that case, I think your answer is correct. I'll bring question to the initial form.