# How to call parameterised constructor present in a class which annotated with @Component inside the another class annotated @Service

Tags: java, spring

I have a requirement where I want to call a parameterised constructor of a class annotated with @Component inside another class which is annotated  with @Service

feel free if you didn't get my question.

```
@Service
Class ServiceClass{



//here I  want to create ComponentClass instance by Spring.
Result result=new ComponentClass(sending data to get result);


}


@Component
Class ComponentClass {

  Component(received data){

  }

}
```

Comment: by using Application Context I'll get bean of Component Class but not a constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try "Autowired" keyword. It says "Hey Spring Framework try to initialize the variable for me".

```
@Autowired
Result result=new ComponentClass(sending data to get result);
```

Comment: yes it is working fine but how do I know that bean is created by Spring

Comment: If you want to deeply analyze when bean is creating. Take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4454209/when-is-a-spring-bean-instantiated) .

Comment: With `@Autowired` annotation, You commit `result` object will be part of Spring Framework. You can use `System.out.println("Object created")` in constructor method to see object is creating by the framework.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you define a `@Servive` or a `@Component` a bean of that type will be created (keep in mind that all beans are singletons).
A bean can be injected into any other spring managed bean by making use of this annotation:

```
@Service 
Class ServiceClass{

   @Autowired
   Result result;



}
```

Using beans (components, services etc.) is not always needed and especially in the case, you need an non-singleton class, things can get tricky because of two reasons:

1. You won't be able to use annotations on that class
2. A non-annotated (spring managed bean) class do not support injection.

To inject a bean inside a class that is not annotated you will need to define a spring context:

```
@Component
public class SpringContext implements ApplicationContextAware {

 private static ApplicationContext context

 public static <T extends Object> T getBean(Class<T> beanClass) {
    return context.getBean(beanClass);
 }

 @Override
 public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) throws BeansException {

    SpringContext.context = context;
 }
}
```

and then into any class:

```
Class ServiceClass{
 Result result =  SpringContext.getBean(Result.class);
}
```

where result is a either component or service.